# jQGrid Firefox issue when load nested subgrd

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am facing an issue in JqGrid in Firefox that load nth label of the subgrid by using recursion for nested data.

Subgrid always failed on the 16th level in the nested set of data.

In google chrome and IE its working fine but issuing in Firfox.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="width:20000px">
<table id="list" ></table>
<div id="pager1"></div>
```

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',

    ExpandColClick:true,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
    ],
    subGrid:true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
    subGridRowExpanded:function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        callSubGrid(subgrid_id,row_id);
    }
});

function addGridData(gridId){
    var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}
    ];
    for(var i=0;i< mydata.length;i++){
        jQuery("#"+gridId).jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
    }
}


function callSubGrid(subgrid_id,row_id){
    var time=new Date().valueOf()
    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
    subgrid_table_id = 'row_id'+row_id+'_'+time+'_t';
    pager_id = 'p_'+subgrid_table_id;
    var table=getGridTable(subgrid_table_id,pager_id);

    $('#'+subgrid_id).html(table);

    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
        ],

        subGridOptions:{
            plusicon : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
            minusicon : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            openicon : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
            reloadOnExpand: false,
            selectOnExpand : true,
            expandOnLoad : false
        },

        caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
        subGrid:true,

        subGridRowExpanded:function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            callSubGrid(subgrid_id,row_id);
        }
    });
    addGridData(subgrid_table_id);
}
addGridData('list');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lByiw.png)

Please help me resolve this issue,thanks.

Brijesh Singh

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to redesign the grid, which you try to display and to rewrote the code. All the subgrids, which you create, have the same column headers and the same (unneeded) caption. I think that **TreeGrid** could be better used to display the data.

Remarks to your current code:

- Please, never use `addRowData` in the loop to fill the data in the grid/subgrid, which you create. One should use `data` parameter of grid instead.
- One should *always* use unique `idPrefix` for every subgrid. The `id` of input data will be used as the value of `id` attribute of the row (`id` od `<tr>` elements). Thus one can get id duplicates. The usage of `idPrefix`, for example, `idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_"` will set the value of `id` attribute based on the prefix and the value of `id` properties of input data. As the result you prevent id duplicates on the HTML page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My basic problem is the code working fine with the IE and Chrome but in Firefox the code has failed when I click on the 16th level of the nested set of the sub-grid.

Comment: @BrijeshSingh: You are welcome! You code, which you posted, is wrong even if you don't see any problem in IE and Chrome (see Remarks to the code). Moreover, if you want to report **a bug** then you should post the exact information about the version of jqGrid, which you use and the fork of jqGrid, which you use ([free jqGrid](), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS]() or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The best would be if you prepare the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem.